# How to use a non-const member function inside a const member function?

Tags: c++, constants, function-qualifier

Following are a simple C++ struct and a class for 3D vector and 3x3 matrix. As you can see the subscript operator is overloaded for both of them. I return a reference to the data members from them in order to be able to assign to those members like `vec[0] = 5.0;`, `mat[0] = vec3(2.0);` and `mat[0][0] = 3.0;` etc. Now I declare another operator for `mat3`, the plus(+) operator which should not modify the matrix itself but should return a new matrix as the sum. How can I make this non-modifying + operator as `const`?

#### Vector

```
struct vec3 {
    typedef double value_type;
    vec3::value_type x, y, z;

    vec3(const vec3::value_type x,
         const vec3::value_type y,
         const vec3::value_type z)
    : x{x}, y{y}, z{z} {}

    vec3(const vec3::value_type w)
    : vec3(w, w, w) {}

    vec3()
    : vec3(0.0) {}

    // this works because [] operator is not used
    vec3 operator+(const vec3& v) const {
        return vec3(this->x + v.x, this->y + v.y, this->z + v.z);
    }

    vec3::value_type& operator[](const std::size_t index) {
        switch(index) {
        case 0:
            return x;
        case 1:
            return y;
        case 2:
            return z;
        default:
            throw std::invalid_argument("vec3 supports upto 3(0-2) elements");
        }
    }
};
```

#### Matrix

```
class mat3 {
    std::array<vec3,3> val;
public:
    using vtype = vec3::value_type;
    mat3(const vtype v00, const vtype v01, const vtype v02,
         const vtype v10, const vtype v11, const vtype v12,
         const vtype v20, const vtype v21, const vtype v22) {
        val[0][0] = v00; val[0][1] = v10; val[0][2] = v20;
        val[1][0] = v01; val[1][1] = v11; val[1][2] = v21;
        val[2][0] = v02; val[2][1] = v21; val[2][2] = v22;
    }

    mat3(const vtype m[3][3]) {
        for(std::size_t i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
            for(std::size_t j = 0; j < 3; ++j) {
                val[i][j] = m[j][i];
            }
        }
    }

    mat3(const vtype v)
    : mat3(v, v, v,
           v, v, v,
           v, v, v) {}

    mat3()
    : mat3(0.0) {}

    // how to make it `const`
    mat3 operator+(const mat3& m) {
        mat3 t;
        for(std::size_t i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
            t[i] = val[i] + m[i];
        }
        return std::move(t);
    }

    vec3& operator[](const std::size_t index) {
        switch(index) {
        case 0:
            return val[0];
        case 1:
            return val[1];
        case 2:
            return val[2];
        default:
            throw std::invalid_argument("mat3 supports upto 3(0-2) vec3");
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Was there some particular reason you didn't provide a `const` version of your `operator []` ? (for both of these, honestly, but at *least* for `vec3`).

Comment: @WhozCraig I didn't know it is possible to add another const version besides this one.

Comment: You don't have a const version yet, so there is no "another" and "besides" involved; only "in addition to", and yes, you can.

Comment: Yeah by `another` a wanted to mean another version of this operator, I thought only argument types matter in overloads not the return type, now it's clear.

Comment: `return std::move(t);` should be `return t;`.  This is already a move context, your version inhibits NRVO

Comment: @M.M I heard this term earlier, but didn't really know what that is. So this optimization won't probably even copy the pointer hidden in `std::array`, right?

Comment: There is no pointer hidden in `std::array`, it is most likely a struct containing an array

Comment: @M.M Really? I thought they might keep a pointer to move it quickly. Anyway, so this optimization doesn't even move the term but directly write to the destination variable for the return, right?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could (and should) add a const version for `operator[]`, then you can make `operator+` const, the const version of `operator[]` will be invoked in it.

```
vec3& operator[](const std::size_t index) {
    ...
}
const vec3& operator[](const std::size_t index) const {
~~~~~                                           ~~~~~
    ...
}
```

Note you can overload const and non-const member functions.

See [const-, volatile-, and ref-qualified member functions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/member_functions#const-.2C_volatile-.2C_and_ref-qualified_member_functions) (emphasis mine)

> A non-static member function can be declared with a `const`, `volatile`,
>   or `const` `volatile` qualifier (this qualifier appears after the name of
>   the function in function declaration). **Differently cv-qualified
>   functions have different types and so may overload each other.**
>
> In the body of a cv-qualified function, the `this` pointer is
>   cv-qualified, e.g. in a const member function, only other const member
>   functions may be called normally. (A non-const member function may
>   still be called if `const_cast` is applied or through an access path
>   that does not involve `this`.)

Comment: Wait I can do that? Doesn't overload take only argument types in account?

Comment: @Samik Yes you can, const and non-const member functions does matter, there's an implicit `this` with different type.

Comment: @Samik maybe it is already clear, but anyhow: Yes it is only the argument types that have to be different, thus you could not declare another `const vec3& operator[](const std::size_t index)` beside the one you already have. However `const vec3& operator[](const std::size_t index) const` takes a different argument (it has to be const)

Comment: @tobi303 Yes, you're right. Probably the `const`ness of the member function determines the `const`ness of implicit `this` pointer, as songyuanyao mentioned.

Comment: @Samik yep, when I wrote "takes a different argument" I was actually refering to the implicit `this` parameter